# How this For Loop prints in this way?

Tags: java

I'm learning coding and today I tried this program

```
for (cnt = 1; cnt <= 6; cnt++) {
    for (int j = cnt; j <= 6; j++) {
        System.out.print("*");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

and I don't understand how it prints a reverse pyramid

```
******
*****
****
***
**
*
```

Could you please explain to me?

Comment: `j` is initialized with the value of `cnt`. Every time `cnt` is incremented, it means that `j` is initialized with a higher value, so it takes less iterations to reach `6`.

Answer (score 0):

That is because `int j = cnt` where `cnt` increase, so the second loop would iterate less as `cnt` increase. Consider this
when `cnt = 1`, the second loop would print 6 times
when `cnt = 2`, the second loop would print one less time then before. And so on. So this is what it's going to print:

```
******
*****
****
***
**
*
```

the number of `*` decrease by one in each row.

Answer (score 0):

When `cnt` = 1

```
j = 1 => Print * => The line becomes *
j = 2 => Print * => The line becomes **
j = 3 => Print * => The line becomes ***
j = 4 => Print * => The line becomes ****
j = 5 => Print * => The line becomes *****
j = 6 => Print * => The line becomes ******
After this line breaks
```

When `cnt` = 2

```
j = 2 => Print * => The line becomes *
j = 3 => Print * => The line becomes **
j = 4 => Print * => The line becomes ***
j = 5 => Print * => The line becomes ****
j = 6 => Print * => The line becomes *****
After this line breaks
```

Thus after two iterations of `cnt`, you get the following pattern:

```
******
*****
```

This way, the iterations of `cnt` will go up to `6` and you get the reverse pyramid  pattern

Answer (score 0):

Your outer loop is making the rows. The inner loop prints j-cnt * symbols. Since cnt is going up each row it prints, j-cnt is decreasing with each outer loop iteration. Thus, each row it prints less and less symbols.

Answer (score 0):

In the first iteration of the outer loop the `cnt` value is `1`, `j` in the inner loop is assigned the value of `cnt` which is `1`, so the inner loop will iterate from `1` to `6` inclusive, these are six stars.

In the second iteration of the outer loop the `cnt` value is `2`, `j` in the inner loop is assigned the value of `cnt` which is `2`, so the inner loop will iterate from `2` to `6` inclusive, these are five stars.

In the third iteration of the outer loop the `cnt` value is `3`, `j` in the inner loop is assigned the value of `cnt` which is `3`, so the inner loop will iterate from `3` to `6` inclusive, these are four stars.

...

In the sixth iteration of the outer loop the `cnt` value is `6`, `j` in the inner loop is assigned the value of `cnt` which is `6`, so the inner loop will iterate from `6` to `6` inclusive, this is one star.